# Save Gif in python Telegram bot

Tags: python, telegram, python-telegram-bot

I have a telegram bot, users send GIF images to me, and I want to download them. Is there any way to do this?

I have already tried to download the GIF as a video file, but telegram would not recognize the GIF as video.

Answer (score 0):

in Message object you can find Video object which contains `file_id`, with this identifier your can call `bot.get_file(file_id).download(path)`

for more download options read [documentation](http://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.file.html?highlight=download)